# Python: Problem with raw_input reading a number

Tags: python, raw-input

unfortunately raw_input is not doing what I need it to do. What I am trying to do is get totPrimes = whatever I type in at the prompt. If i replace `while count < totPrimes` with `while count < 50` this script works. If I type 50 into the prompt, this script doesnt work, I'm afraid raw_input isn't the function im looking to use? Here is a snippet of my code:

```
testNum = 3
div = 2
count = 1
totPrimes = raw_input("Please enter the primes: ")

while count < totPrimes :
    while div <= testNum :
```

Comment: consider changing the title to something more adequate. p.e.'Problem with raw_input reading a number', or similar.

Comment: FYI, this is a problem in Python 2.x, since you can compare objects of different types. In Python 3.x it will raise a `TypeError: unorderable types`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do

```
totPrimes = int(totPrimes)
while count < totPrimes:
    # code
```

`raw_input` gives you a string you must convert to an integer or float before making any numeric comparison.

Comment: Although it would be better to do that conversion *before* the loop and save it as a local variable. Otherwise you will be needlessly calling `int` each time around the loop as you do the comparison.

Comment: @ncoghlan you are right. I wrote it that way to show the problem condensed in one line. I updated it to the more efficient version you refer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast totPrimes into an int like this:

```
integer = int(totPrimes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert your raw input in a integer. For your code just change your code as:

```
testNum = 3
div = 2
count = 1
totPrimes = raw_input("Please enter the primes: ")
totPrimes=int(totPrimes)
while count < totPrimes :
    while div <= testNum :
```

Answer (score 0):

The raw_input function always returns a 'string' type [raw_input docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), so we must in this case convert the `totPrimes` 'string' type to an 'int' or 'float' type like this:

```
totPrimes = raw_input("Please enter the primes: ")
totPrimes = float(totPrimes)
```

You can combine them like this:

```
totPrimes = float(raw_input("Please enter the primes: "))
```

In order to compare things in python `count < totPrimes`, the comparison needs to make sense (numbers to numbers, strings to strings) or the program will crash and the `while count < totPrimes :` while loop won't run.

You can use try/except to protect your program. [managing exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

For people taking the course "Programming for Everybody" you can take in hours and rate this way. the if/else statement you should try to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change every number to "hrs" or "rate".

For example: `40*10.50+(h-40)*10.50*1.5` is wrong, `40*r+(h-40)*r*1.5` is right.

Answer (score -1):

Use input then.

Raw input returns string.

input returns int.

Comment: No, `input` in Python 2 evaluates the expression. If you input a stringy expression, it will return a string. If you input a numeric expression, it will return a number (float or int depending on how exactly you expressed it).