# Basic Issue on Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python 2.7.9

I wrote this code below and when I run in the Shell the random number displays, I type it in and then nothing else happens.  I don't get an error message but I don't see why it isn't printing "Good Guess"

```
import random

def guessNumber():  
    myNum = random.randint(1,1000)  
    print myNum  
    guess = raw_input("Guess my Number:")  
    if guess == myNum:  
        print "Good Guess"
```

Comment: You never call anything, and `raw_input` always gives a string.

Comment: (I corrected your indenting.  The problem was that to tell stackoverflow it's code you need to indent everything (including the `import random` and `def ...` )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Problem with raw\_input reading a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762938/python-problem-with-raw-input-reading-a-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that it's reading in the guess as a string.  So it's comparing the string to an integer.  That's always `False`.  Change to

```
guess = int(raw_input("Guess my Number: "))
```

To make it robust

```
try:
    guess = int(raw_input("Guess my Number: "))
except ValueError:
    print "that wasn't an integer."
    continue
```

Then you can put a loop around this as you see fit.