# Python 3 '==' or 'if' function not producing correct result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on improving my python 3 skills by creating this simple game.

Very basic, you have a random number between 1 and 5 and if you guess it correct them you win. However for reason reason whenever I try to run it all I get is the "you lose" result even when my test print shows I got the same number.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import random

B = input("Pick a number between 1 and 5:" )
F = random.randrange(1, 5, 1)

if B == F:
    print("You win")
else:
    print("You lose")
print (B, F)
```

I can't tell if it's the `==` function that is causing the problem or the `if` function is wrong for some reason but it doesn't look it.

Comment: One value is an integer, the other a string..

Comment: Python 2 answer: [Python: Problem with raw\_input reading a number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5762938)

Comment: Try to print `type(B), type(F)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah, that would be the reason. I didn't know you couldn't get the two to interact together

Comment: This code would work fine as is in Python 2.

Comment: @DavidGreydanus: Sure, but OTOH the Python 2 `input()` function is best avoided.

Comment: Next time you have this problem, debug it and check what is B and F. Or do a print(repr(...))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

B = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 5 ")) # Input goes inside int()
F = random.randrange(1,5,1)

if B == F:
    print("you win")
else:
    print("you lose")
print(B, F)
```

**Side Note:** The code you produced actually works fine in Python 2 where `input` returns an `int` if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the `input` in order to get an `int`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import random

B = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 5 " ))
F =(random.randrange(1,5,1))

if B == F:
    print("you win")
else:
    print("you lose")
print (B, F)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
B = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 5 " ))
```

Change the type for the input to an integer.