# Having trouble with a code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert how many years old you are into days:

```
print "age into days converter"
name = raw_input("What is your name: ")
age = raw_input("How old are you: ")
days_in_years = 365
age_in_days = age * days_in_years
print "You are %s days old" %age_in_days
```

However, it prints your age 365 times instead of multiplying it. I tried using input, int(,
and trying to convert it to a float value but it still wasn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Problem with raw\_input reading a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762938/python-problem-with-raw-input-reading-a-number)

Comment: "but it stlll wasn't working" so what went wrong? Show us where you went wrong and we can help explain that aspect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `age_in_days = age * days_in_years` with `age_in_days = int(age) * days_in_years` so that `age_in_days` is a number and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` will return a string which you multiply by an `int` resulting in *string repetition*, not int multiplication.

Wrap it in an `int` call to get the result you need

```
age = int(raw_input("How old are you: "))
```